# Use attribute to inject Header/Footer into view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I want to write an attribute to inject header/footer into the pages.
here is how I want the end code to look like:

```
[HeaderFooter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

HeaderFooter code:

```
<header>
    // header code here
</header>


<footer >
    // footer code here
</footer >
```

view code:

```
<html>

//header to appear here.

PAGE CONTENT

//footer to appear here.

</html>
```

Question is: How to write the attribute code in a way that it injects the html code directly to view and not add any more code within the actionresult?

Comment: This is quite unusual for ASP.Net MVC to do that... Usually you'd use layout files to add footer/header... On other hand [action filter attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) can easily modify result any way you want - so you can try `HeaderFooter:ActionFilterAttribute`

Comment: correct. Im doing this because I want to make the attribute conditional. It would be very useful if you have a number of layout and want to customize from one actionresult to another.

Comment: You may want to ask separate question on what you *actually* want to achieve - I suspect that your current path is not the best one and thus causing you a lot of pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, it's unusual for an action attribute to the writing to the view output. This would probably be better suited using `section` declarations in the view or in the layout, or by customizing the view engine.

The reason it doesn't fit is because your code will be writing HTML to the response, ideally to keep a separation of concerns, your views should be handling everything to do with what is rendered.

However to answer your question:

```
public class HeaderFooterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<header></header>");
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<footer></footer>");
    }
}
```

Comment: +0: Sample not going to produce acceptable results as it will write HTML *before* start of the page in most cases. You need to return custom `ActionResult` that wraps actual result and render HTML at appropriate time.